# Javascript Replace Method clarification

Tags: javascript, replace

1- What does $3$2$1 means in:

```
var s = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
var re = /(\S+)(\s+)(\S+)/g;
// Exchange each pair of words.
var result = s.replace(re, "$3$2$1");
document.write(result);

// Output:  quick The fox brown over jumps lazy the dog.
```

2- and $0, $1, $2 in:

```
function f2c(s1) {
    // Initialize pattern.
    var test = /(\d+(\.\d*)?)F\b/g;

    // Use a function for the replacement.
    var s2 = s1.replace(test,
      function($0,$1,$2)
           { 
           return((($1-32) * 5/9) + "C");
           }
        )
    return s2;
}
document.write(f2c("Water freezes at 32F and boils at 212F."));

// Output: Water freezes at 0C and boils at 100C.
```

Note, thanks for your replies, I understand number 1, but number 2 is a bit harder and I am struggling to get around it.

Thanks,

Youssef

Comment: [Submatch replacement pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1- In reg exp, parenthesis mean capturing pattern and $X means reference to the captured elements:

```
var re = /(\S+)(\s+)(\S+)/g;
            ^     ^    ^
            |     |    |
            $1    $2   $3
```

In this pattern, replacing it with `$1$2$3` will take the 3 matches and reverse them, so it'll take "The quick" and turn it into "quick The".

2- $0 references the entire matched subexpression. The given function will not use $0 nor $2 but just $1 to convert °F to C°

Comment: Thanks, please see my update, I understand part one now, but number 2 is confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

It represents the groups inside of the parenthesis. `$1` is the expression matched by the first `(\S+)`, `$2` is the expression matched by the `(\s+)` and `$3` is the last group.

Answer (score 1):

In regex, a set of parentheses tells the engine to create a back reference. This is then stored for you to use later, for instance in a replace. The back references are numbered 1, 2, 3 an so on. In your case, `$1` refers to the first `\S+`, $2 refers to `\s+` and $3 refers to the final `\S+`.

Here, `\S+` matches anything but whitespace and `\s+` whitespace, so I'd expect this particular problem to have `$1` equal `The`, `$2` =  (space) and `$3` = `quick`. When replace, you're essentially swapping `The` and `quick` around, by using the back reference in a different order to the original.